# Invalid use of template-name

Tags: c++, templates

I get an error that says "invalid use of template-name 'linkedList' without an argument list." Could somebody tell me what an argument list is? When I tried researching the error, it looks like it has to do with where I define my constructor, but I can't figure out anything beyond that.

This is a very abbreviated version of my class:

```
Template <class T>
class linkedList
{
public:
    node *mStart;
    linkedList():mStart(NULL)
    {}
}
```

And this is where I get my error in a different .h file.

```
linkedList que;
```

Comment: And also the template argument, just like the error says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The keyword `template` is lower-case.
2. I'm guessing you want to use your template argument as part of the node type.
3. You're missing a semicolon at the end of your class declaration.
4. You're missing the template argument in your variable declaration.

Put it all together, and you get:

```
template <class T>
class linkedList
{
public:
    T *mStart; // or node<T> *mStart; (hat tip: @chris)
    linkedList():mStart(NULL) {}
};

linkedList<int> que;
```

Comment: He's not missing the constructor body. My mistake... lol

Comment: @0x499602D2 Haha... I missed it too. :-)

Comment: Based on `que`, the OP might have wanted `node<T> *mStart;`.

Comment: @chris Good point... Updated the post.

Comment: Thank you! I'll copy/paste my code directly from codeblocks next time, because issues #1 & 3 you talked about were just typos I made on this post.